# Reading and printing file contents in a desired manner in PHP

Tags: php, string, file-handling

I have text file ($test_filename) which has the following contents:

```
boy
girl
man
woman
child
```

I need to read this text file in PHP and store the content in a string in the following manner:

```
$output = (type, 'child', 'woman', 'man', 'girl', 'boy')
```

I am trying with the following code but I am getting extra quote and spaces.

```
 $file = file_get_contents($test_filename);
 $revstr = "";
 $teststr = explode(" ",$file);
 for($i=count($teststr)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
      $revstr = $revstr.$teststr[$i]." ";
 }

 echo $revstr;

 $str = "'" . implode("','", explode(' ', $revstr)) . "'";

 echo $str;

 $output = "(type, $str)";    

 echo $output;
```

I am getting the following output. There is an extra space before each word (except for last word-boy). There is an extra comma and double quote at the end.

```
(type, ' child', ' woman', ' man', ' girl', 'boy','')
```

Could anyone please help me in getting the desired exact output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which returns an array, then implode with your glue including spacing, then just concatenate the start and the end.

```
<?php
$array = file($test_filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

echo "(type, '".implode("', '", $array)."')";
```

https://3v4l.org/fkuJo

**Result:**

```
(type, 'boy', 'girl', 'man', 'woman', 'child')
```

If you want it reversed, use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

```
echo "(type, '".implode("', '", array_reverse($array))."')";
```

```
(type, 'child', 'woman', 'man', 'girl', 'boy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, but this would be a lot neater if you made use of more of PHP's internal functionality. Use an array to store the values rather than just directly manipulating a string using `implode` and `explode`, and deal with each step individually. It'll make your code a lot more adaptable in future.

```
$test_filename = 'people.txt';

// Read the file into an array, ignoring line endings and empty lines
$lines = file($test_filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Reverse the order
$people = array_reverse($lines);

// Surround each string in quotes
$quoted = array_map(function ($e) { return "'{$e}'"; }, $people);

// Build up a single comma-separated string
$str = implode(', ', $quoted);

// Create desired output format
$output = "(type, $str)";

// Display
echo $output;
```

> (type, 'child', 'woman', 'man', 'girl', 'boy')

You can obviously reduce this into far fewer lines if you want.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks!